# iOS Safari - not receiving web push notifications sent by cronjob or backend

Tags: javascript, ios, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

Web push on iOS is a new thing announced earlier this year. Upon reading and seeing examples of the implementation it made me believe it is fully supported. When I tried implementing my self I was only able to make it work on the frontend side, but sending the push notification from the backend (PHP) didn't work for iOS only, while on MacOS Chrome, Android Chrome and Samsung Internet it worked as expected.

I followed [this simple guide](https://devtails.xyz/@adam/how-to-setup-web-push-notifications-in-ios-safari) on implementing it on the frontend. For storing subscriptions to my database and sending notifications from the backend I used [this Symfony package](https://packagist.org/packages/bentools/webpush-bundle).

On the frontend side I:

- registered a service worked;
- requested a "notifications" permission;
- when granted - sent the subsription to backend to store it;

Here is my script:

```
import convertVapidKey from 'convert-vapid-public-key';

window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
  // 1. Register ServiceWorker
  if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
    console.warn('[Service Worker] Service Worker is not available for your device or environment!');
    return;
  }

  let registration;

  try {
    registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(window.serviceWorkerPath, {
      scope: '/'
    });
    console.info('[Service Worker] Registration succeeded:', registration);
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn('[Service Worker] Registration failed:', error);
    return;
  }

  // 2. Subscribe to Notifications
  if (
    !window.webpushServerKey ||
    !('Notification' in window) ||
    !('PushManager' in window)
  ) {
    console.warn('[WebPush Client] Web push is not available for your device or environment!');
    return;
  }

  try {
    if (await Notification.requestPermission() === 'granted') {
      await subscribe();
      await registration.showNotification('Congratulations! ', {
        body: 'You have subscribed to the notifications successfully! '
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn('[WebPush Client] Subscription failed:', error);
  }

  async function subscribe() {
    try {
      // Subscribe on client
      const subscription = await registration.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: convertVapidKey(window.webpushServerKey)
      });

      // Store subscription
      await fetch('/webpush/', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        cache: 'default',
        headers: new Headers({
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify({ subscription })
      });

      console.info('[WebPush Client] Subscription succeeded:', subscription);
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn('[WebPush Client] Subscription failed:', error);
    }
  }
});
```

Now when user on any device (even in iOS Safari web-app) enters the website, they are prompted with the notifications permission confirmation and once confirmed, they successfully get the "congratulations" notification sent from the frontend.

I also added a `push` event listener to the service worker to receive push notifications sent from the backend at any time of the day even when the website is not being currently used.

```
// sw.js
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
  try {
    const json = event.data.json();
    const title = json.title || '';
    const options = json.options || {};
    console.info('[Service Worker] Push event received with:', json);
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn('[Service Worker] Push notification failed:', error);
  }
});
```

For some reason, whenever I push the notification from the backend, on all devices the `push` listener is executed except on iOS Safari web app...

```
/** @var \BenTools\WebPushBundle\Sender\PushMessageSender */
protected $sender;

// ...

$message = new \BenTools\WebPushBundle\Model\Message\PushNotification($title, [
  PushNotification::BODY => $notification->getBody(),
  //...
]);
$this->sender->push($notification->createMessage(), $subscriptions);
```

I started searching why and noticed that, despite endless examples on the internet using service worker push event, in the [browser support table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/push_event#browser_compatibility) it states that the event is not yet supported on iOS Safari. Am I doing something wrong in my code? Is there other way to achieve it for iOS than push event if it's not supported?

P.S. I have `Notifications`, `Push API` and `Service Workers` enabled in the Safari's *Experimental Features* settings.

Comment: Is your (web) app installed (as ipa/from App Store)? Or is your app a web app added to the home screen? Or is it "just" a website (not installed, nor added to home screen). At the moment it seems only Web Apps that are "added to the homescreen" (on iOS >=16.4) can receive Web Push notifications. "Normal apps" (=wrapped web apps using something like pwabuilder) cannot receive Web Push notifications at the moment.

Comment: It is a web app added to the home screen

Comment: I got it resolved, I was way too focussed on the docs stating that push event is not yet supported on iOS Safari... I started debugging BE instead and noticed that the call to the apple endpoint returned `403` due to missing subject of `mailto:xxx`. I added it and now I am receiving the `push` events on the iOS web app added to the homescreen.

Comment: @IgnasDamunskis can you say the push event is the major factor that made this to work for you?
I'm currently trying to make it work but nothing is working out yet...I'm using push notification from firebase

Answer (score 2):

[CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/push-api) suggests that for push notifications to Safari on iOS (16.4 to 16.5):

> Requires website to first be added to the Home Screen.

[Here's a blog](https://webkit.org/blog/13878/web-push-for-web-apps-on-ios-and-ipados/) describing the feature:

> Now with iOS and iPadOS 16.4, we are adding support for Web Push to Home Screen web apps.

Comment: In the question when I said `iOS Safari web app` I meant PWA. Push event is not triggered there even tho my service worker is registered and notifications permission granted

Comment: Ok, so that means you have it 'added to your Home Screen'?

Comment: yes it is a web app added to home screen

Comment: Got it resolved, the issue was on the BE in the end.. I rewarded you with the bounty since you were the only answer which technically is correct.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.